# Passing array of objects to a master page's content page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an array of objects that are loaded server side in the C# code from a text file I am attempting to pass this array to one of the content pages. It worked without issue when I did not use a master page but once I added the master page it no longer works.

Here is the aspx.cs page:

```
 // Convert list of objects to a json array
 string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(clownIncidents);
 cs.RegisterArrayDeclaration("markers", jsonString);
```

When I try to access it on the content page it says markers is undefined:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" 
    Runat="Server">    
    <div id="map" ></div>  
    <script src ="jss/Maps.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
    key=MYKEYcallback=initMap"></script>  
</asp:Content>
```

Lastly here is the JavaScript referenced in the content page:

```
function initMap() {
    alert(markers);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because the JavaScript code generated from `cs.RegisterArrayDeclaration("markers", jsonString);` appears in the HTML after your script in the content page. So, when your script runs, the variable `markers` is not yet defined.

To overcome this you need to add a new `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` in your Master page, which must be after the `<form runat="server">` element and use that ContentPlaceHolder to have your JavaScript.

For example, your Master page will be:

```
<form runat="server">
<%-- Here is your Master page --%>
</form>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ScriptContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

And then, in your .aspx content page, you can have your script like this (add the following snippet in the end of your .aspx page):

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ScriptContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <div id="map" ></div>  
    <script src ="jss/Maps.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
    key=MYKEYcallback=initMap"></script> 
</asp:Content>
```